# How to configure login timeout in mobilefirst Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using custom authenticator and login module with session independent mode set to "true" which is a default. I would like to know how to configure login time out and as I do not want the user to be logged in for ever. I am using MFP Server version is 7.1.0.00.20151107-1647.

Answer (score 0):

If the client reached the time-out you specified, then you send an Alert that the session has timed out and you route the user to the login screen adding  the client side

```
WL.Client.setHeartbeatInterval ()
```

or

**set for  Idle session timeout in minutes**

adding  `worklight.properties` file

```
 serverSessionTimeout=30
```